# IPython workflow (edit, run)

Tags: python, user-interface, ipython, python-idle

Is there a GUI for IPython that allows me to open/run/edit Python files? My way of working in IDLE is to have two windows open: the shell and a .py file. I edit the .py file, run it, and interact with the results in the shell.

Is it possible to use IPython like this? Or is there an alternative way of working?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python and similar SO discussions.

Comment: None of the acronyms used on that page matches what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When I'm working with python, I usually have two terminal windows open - one with IPython, and the other with a fairly customized Vim.

Two good resources:

- http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/
- http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/python-and-vim-make-your-own-ide/

---

Though it sounds like what you want is IPython's magic function `%ed`/`%edit`:

An example of what you can do:

```
In [72]: %ed
IPython will make a temporary file named: c:\docume~1\wjwe312\locals~1\temp\ipython_edit_ar8veu.py
```

In the file I put:

```
x = "Hello World"
print 3
```

After saving and quitting the file:

```
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
3
Out[72]: "x = 'Hello world'\nprint 3\n"

In [73]: x
Out[73]: 'Hello world'
```

You can define functions or anything else - just remember that the contents of the file will be executed when you close it.

Another similar workflow is to `cd` to the directory containing your Python script that you're editing with your favorite editor. Then you can `%run` the script from within IPython and you'll have access to everything defined in the file. For instance, if you have the following in the file `test.py` in your `/home/myself` directory:

```
    class Tester(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print "hi"

    def knightme(name):
        print "Hello, Sir ", name
```

Then you can do the following:

```
In [42]: cd /home/myself
/home/myself

In [43]: %run test.py # <Tab> autocomplete also works

In [44]: knightme('John')
Hello, Sir  John

In [45]: t = Tester()
Hi
```

Either a mix or one of those workflows should give you something very similar to the way you're used to working in IDLE.

Comment: If you just want to edit a file from ipython without executing it, do `%edit -x <file>`.

Comment: ma3204, that is incredibly useful! I'm probably barely competent with IPython - I just use it like an advanced "regular" shell. It's got a lot of features I just don't know about.

Comment: But is there a way to use IPython *within* IDLE?  Because the standard interpreter sucks, and the Windows Command Prompt sucks.  I want the IPython interpreter in a console that actually works well with it.

Comment: @endolith, You can always install cygwin ;) - Actually I used Console2 for a while and it worked pretty well.

Comment: @Wayne What would installing Cygwin accomplish?

Comment: @endolith, not having to use windows command prompt, of course.

Comment: Oh.  That's what I want, but why does that require installing an entire operating system?  Can't alternate terminals be written by themselves?

Comment: I guess technically speaking it would be possible - but I'm not aware of any real efforts to do such things under Windows. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is probably the only thing that I've seen - and you can actually set it up to use IPython as the shell, and you can do most things in IPYthon that you can do inside the cmd.exe, so that might be useful for you.

Comment: @endolith, IdleX supports running IPython within IDLE.

Comment: The problem is, how can you *RE-EDIT* the result you had in 72?  %edit 72, or %recall 72 just gives the %edit-line. It's so irritating to always loose the work, not being able to re-run.

Comment: To answer myself: you do   %edit _72   to get the output! :D Awesome. Finally.

Comment: But can you send selected code to IPython from vim?

Comment: @Alcott the quickest answer i have is to use tmux send-keys, but i bet ipython provides another way

Comment: @odinho-Velmont, thanks for the tip about the %edit _72.. %edit is pretty good, but without this tip, its pretty much useless.. :)

Comment: @Alcott, you can use vim-ipython. It uses tmux to send code blocks to ipython. It works pretty well on linux.. but probably can be made to work on Windows with some work.

Answer (score 17):

[Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), previously known as SPyderlib / Spyder2

Pretty lightweight, fast and support almost all [features](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/Features) you will ever need to work with a python project.  It can edit and run .py files in an embedded IPython instance and then interact with them, set breakpoints, etc.

[image] [full-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb0pK.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try Spyder, I have spent all day trying to find an IDE which has the functionality of ipython and Spyder just kicks it out of the park..

Autocomplete is top notch right from install, no config files and all that crap, and it has an Ipython terminal in the corner for you to instantly run your code.

big thumbs up

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/). Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/). Unfortunately, it only works on Windows, but also runs perfectly in Wine.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the work-flow under `Matlab`, then you probably should try the following two:

**1**, **Try the combination of `Spyder` and `Vim`.**

- Edit python files in `Vim` (`Spyder` can reload the file automatically)
- Run the code in `Spyder` (in the same interpreter, which is important for me):
- Use **`F9`** to run the current file
- **`Ctrl+F9`** to run the selected block

**2**, **Use `Vim` + `conque-shell`**. ([on google code](http://code.google.com/p/conque/))

- Open your preferred `Python interpreter` in `Vim`,

  e.g., just **`:ConqueTermSplit python`**.
- then visual select some `Python` code
- press **`F9`** to paste and run it in the `Python interpreter buffer`.

*Note: a few more:*

- `:ConqueTermVSplit python`,
- `:ConqueTerm python`
- `:ConqueTermVSplit rlwrap python`

  If your interpretor misses `readline`, you can use `rlwrap`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

Once you are done with installing ipython.

Start ipython from terminal (just hit `ipython` in the ternminal)

To run `ravi.py` file all you need to do is

```
%run ravi.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) supports IPython within IDLE, as well as the %edit magic. You can run your files from the IDLE editor within the IPython shell many ways, either by F5 (run everything), F9 (run a selection), or Ctrl+Enter (run a subcode).

Answer (score 1):

You might like [PySlices](http://code.google.com/p/wxpysuite/)...

It's kind of a shell/editor hybrid that lets you save your session as special (barely) modified python files called .pyslice files.

It's now part of [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php), so just install that (v2.8.11 or later) and run "python -m wx.py.PySlices" on the command line to launch it.

That said, I still end up using an external editor for scripts (geany).

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest excellent plugin for vim that makes two-way integration between Vim and IPython: vim-ipython.

From project page on http://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython:

> Using this plugin, you can send lines or whole files for IPython to execute, and also get back object introspection and word completions in Vim, like what you get with: object? and object. in IPython.

This plugin has one big limitation: it doesn't support python 3 (it's planned).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use what @Wayne suggested, a combination of vim and ipython...

However, if you'd prefer a different approach, take a look at [spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/).

As of the latest version (1.1) ipython should be fully integrated.  If you download an earlier version, things will work fine with ipython as an external shell, but you won't get a few of spyder's nifty features (like viewing all of the currently defined variables in the workspace window).

Spyder is definitely a bit heavyweight, but it's an interesting project.

Another (very, very, new) similar project to take a look at is [iep](http://code.google.com/p/iep/).  It will (sort-of) work with ipython as shell, and I'd be willing to be bet that nicer ipython integration will be along before too long.  At any rate, iep is essentially a more lightweight alternative to spyder.

Both of these are oriented towards scientific computing, and so have nice integration with things like matplotlib (and thus can automatically run gui main loops in a seperate thread). They're not quite like "normal" IDE's but they may fill the niche you're looking for quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autoreload module in IPython to automatically reload code.

Open `jupyter qtconsole` or `jupyter console` and type:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
from your_work_file import *
```

Now every time you save `your_work_file.py`, it will be automatically reloaded.

Hint: if you want this to happen automatically, put the followinglines in your `ipython_config.py` file:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']         
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ptpython`. It has much better integration with `VIM`. You can directly edit in VIM by just pressing `V`. It also allows browsing your history.. so you can pretty much code in the shell, and incrementally build up your code.

If you are already familiar with `ipython`, you can check the advantages of `ptpython` here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDgIDslyAFM

Answer (score 0):

I just use the exclamation mark (`!`) to run `vi` as a shell command

```
In [1]: !vi myScript.py
```

and when done with editing I just quit `vi` to get back to the Ipython shell.

To run the script one can then use

```
In [2]: %run myScript.py
```

as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643234/2314737) and not `!python ...` because the Python version in `ipython` might be different from the one in the underlying shell.

If you want to dump some code in a file use the *magic* `%%writefile`

```
 In [3]:%%writefile myScript.py
    ...: print("hello")
    ...: 
    ...:
```

**Be careful** because this will overwrite `myScript.py`. To append use `%%writefile -a`.