# Import an unfinished python script into IPython

Tags: python, ipython

Sometimes, I want to add new features into a Python application. Usually, we can explore and test these new features in IPython interactive environment. It is inconvenient, however, that type in the already finished codes each time.

So, is it possible to import an exist python script into IPython for further modification?

Comment: Uh, possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438531/ipython-workflow-edit-run

Comment: This cannot be done with IPython.  Suggest moving up to Spyder which is more of a full IDE with separate editor and console windows and its File menu has open as well as save and close selections.  If your python distro does not have Spyder it is bundled with Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ipython notebook.

```
$ ipython notebook
```

then open your existing code and do a further modification.