# python vim tmux linux - copy multiple lines from vim to ipython

Tags: python, linux, vim, ipython

I am trying to copy a block of text (im in linux debian) from vim to ipython
I select the block of text "yank", exit vim with ctrl-Z, enter ipython and shift-insert.

However it always only paste the first line of my originaly copied block of text..

Any idea how to paste multi lines?

(Edit by @maxymoo to add a MCVE)

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get install python-pip tmux vim
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install ipython
```

Now start up a tmux session, `C-b %` to split pane, start `vim` and enter the following lines:

```
print("first line")
print("second line")
```

Copy it to tmux clipboard with `C-b [ C-space <arrow keys to select all> M-w`

Switch to the other pane with `C-b o` and start an `ipython` session.
Paste the text with `C-b ]`

Output:

```
In [1]: print("first line")                                                                                                                                    
first line                                                                                                                                                     

In [2]:
```

The paste works properly if I force line-continuation mode by using `%%time` cell magic:

```
In [3]: %%time
   ...: print("first line")
   ...: print("second line")
   ...:
first line
second line
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 42.2 us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

## Use your window manager

Highlight the text with your mouse and then middle click to paste. Some versions of Python have this behavior turned off, which is silly.

## Use tmux

I have [this tmux.conf](https://gist.github.com/waynew/bc84f66799a6529ffc9e0bfa128f51c4)

So for me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> (you can think of it as `[`opy) then I just use vim-like keys to move the keyboard, <kbd>space</kbd> to start marking, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> pastes.

## Use `xclip`

```
$ cat yourfile.py | xclip
```

should copy your entire file into your system clipboard. Then you should be able to paste like normal.

## Use the system clipboard

`"+y` should yank from vim into the system clipboard. `"+yy` if you haven't visually selected text. Depending on how your environment works this may or may not work. Then your <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> option *should* work.

## Use `ipython` magic functions

`%run` or `%ed(it)`

[`%edit`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-edit) lets you edit a specified file. Or, it will make you a temp file if you don't give it a filename. You can also give it the name of a function that you've defined and it will let you edit the function. On exit, it will execute your file. It uses the `EDITOR` env var to determine what editor to launch.

[`%run`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-run) using the specified filename will execute your file.

> This is similar to running at a system prompt python file args, but with the advantage of giving you IPython’s tracebacks, and of loading all variables into your interactive namespace for further use (unless -p is used, see below).

You can find another answer where I talk about my IPython workflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531548/344286).

Comment: does the tmux solution really work for you? when i try it, i get exactly same behavior as OP (tested on debian and mac), only the first line is executed, the rest is ignored. somehow the tmux "paste" is different than system clipboard paste, which automatically goes into line continuation mode. (this is important if I'm on a remote server where I don't have system clipboard)

Comment: Are you sure that you've actually copied things using tmux's copy? You'll probably want to do a region select (`v` after you start to copy, at least with my tmux.conf)...

Comment: yeah it's definitely copying, i can paste it no problems into another vim for example, i can also paste no problems with cmd-v, just with `C-a ]` the ipython command executes after the first line

Comment: @maxymoo can you make an MCVE?

Comment: I've added a MCVE to the question

Comment: i have the same problem (just copies the first line). copying from system clipboard works fine though

Answer (score 1):

When Typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> while editing in vim keep in mind that you are back to the shell terminal so you cannot use any vim commands instead you need to use the shortcuts provided by your terminal of `Copy` and `Paste` by checking them in terminal `Edition > Preferences > shortcuts` or you can use your mouse clicks.

***Note:*** in case you have a problem of copying the text using the mouse in vim you need to turn it off by this command `:set mouse=`

Comment: yes this is what i do by pasting using the command shift +insert;
it works but only paste the first line of any multi lines blocks - which is my problem

Comment: what do you mean by test ?

Comment: yes, same - also it is strange that when text is already in the clipboard, i cannot yank at all from vim - ie yanking from vim doesnt overwrite what is already in the clipboard